# Can I sign a text with a Bitcoin address using PHP only?

Tags: signature, php, pgp

I have the following...

**Bitcoin Address**: 1H2zzoAncRcQYihgTMYtX55ioXYErmYQQC

**Public Key**: 021FE07FBBB27AD176F1E082950474CD6252FB86751B893BC0887962B008830798

**WIF Key**: Kzy3fea4xCwLczAj3g8TYvDw6QRKCMqvVZX2J7vaXgy78VhieRdV

**HEX Key**: 6FCE4A50EA529B2D4B3E9671B5B0AA0D5D19266D778FB005F25AE4599D5D2BA0

**I need to sign**: Just a sample text

**I want this result**: *H9saC8UiO0n++3dHZev/apRXkQCrqFofvW9vMpzWqPKsYTNvx/4bdtbdcMORGvNblQknT34UErnwEM3fxTZII0U=*

How can I code it only in PHP without calling any API or invoking any JS library?

Comment: The ultimate documentation is the Bitcoin Core source code.  So the short answer to your question is: read their code and reimplement in your language.

Comment: BTW, **never** use this address for anything ever again since the priv key is published.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I created a PHP library for cryptocurrency. You can use [this library](https://github.com/ItayRosen/cryptophp/) to achieve what you want.

You can use it like this:

```
require('CryptoPHP.php');
$wif_key = 'Kzy3fea4xCwLczAj3g8TYvDw6QRKCMqvVZX2J7vaXgy78VhieRdV'; //this is your wif key
$private_key = $this -> wif2key($wif_key); //get the wif key to a hex private key
$hash = 'Just a sample text'; //this is what you're trying to sign.

$signature = $this -> sign($hash,$private_key);
```

Comment: Not working. Throwing Fatal Error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in sign_message.php on line 4.  

sign_message.php contains your code.